# How to Run an iPod app on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uidevice

How do we run a iPod app on a iPad? Which flag do we need to enable? I want to run it like it run on a iPad simulator.

Comment: Er, what are you asking? Are you trying to run it on the physical device or in the iPad Simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Project/Target's Build Settings set Targeted Device Family to iPhone/iPad.

Or if you're using Xcode 4 you can set Devices, in the Summary Tab of your Target, to iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Why does it crash on simulator? I enable this to iPhone/iPad and it crashed on iPad simulator.

Comment: You need to give more info what happens when it crashes?